# When uploading different file types what is preferred that comes first file selection or asking the user to identify the type of file?

Tags: web-app, files, file-input

When having users upload a mixed set of file types that could be used for different purposes is it better to have the user select the files for upload from the system or ask what the files are for first before asking to select the files for upload? This is for a desktop-focused web app.

Comment: can you explain a bit of your use case? Right now it's too borad and answers will depend on that

Answer (score 0):

The main action for your app in that situation is to "upload files", that's why the user clicked on the CTA or whatever other button you they clicked on.

So you should have them get the files first, then ask for reasons after, this should lead to less churn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your workflow, but my first impression is to let the user upload the files first and then decide what to do with them. That way you can validate the files and make sure they are compatible with whatever task they want to use them for.

Also, make sure you let the user know of any limitations around file type or size before they attempt to upload. This could just be some small text near the 'upload' button.